# Allure +Junit 4 - allure-results folder is not created

Tags: java, junit4, allure

I'm trying to use allure with junit 4
I added relevant items to pom file, but the allure-resultfolder is not created
when I run `mvn clean test -Dtest=allurejunit4.class && mvn allure:report`
I get `[ERROR] Directory C:\Users\testing\sanity\target\allure-results not found.`

I added to pom :
in dependecies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>${allure.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

in plugins:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
                <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                    <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                    <argLine>-javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"</argLine>
                    <properties>
                        <property>
                            <name>listener</name>       
                     
  <value>io.qameta.allure.junit4.AllureJunit4</value>
                        </property>
                    </properties>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

after I update maven and run `mvn clean test -Dtest=allurejunit4.class && mvn allure:report`
I get:

```
[INFO] Generate Allure report to C:\Users\git\testing\target\site/allure-maven-plugin
[ERROR] Directory C:\Users\git\testing\target\allure-results not found.
[WARNING] Allure report was skipped because there is no results directories found.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  8.579 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-08-28T09:13:47+03:00
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:
`<skipTests>true</skipTests>` need to be false,
and `maven-surefire-plugin` version was not fit